# File.exist? not working when directory name has special characters

Tags: ruby

File.exist? in not working with directory name having special characters. for something like given below 
path = "/home/cis/Desktop/'El%20POP%20que%20llevas%20dentro%20Vol.%202'/*.mp3"

it works fine but if it has letters like ñ its returns false.
Plz help with this.

Comment: which version of ruby do you use (1.8.7 or greater)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Make sure you're running 1.9.2 or greater and put `# encoding: UTF-8` at the top of your file (which must be in UTF-8 and your editor must support it).

If you're running MRI(i.e. not JRuby or other implementation) you can add environment variable `RUBYOPT=-Ku` instead of `# encoding: UTF-8` to the top of each file.